# Regex Parsing: Copy the content of one html tag to another html tag

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have this 2 html meta tags:

```
<meta name="description" content="Example"/>

<meta property="og:description" content="I love my car mostly."/>
```

I need to copy the content of the first meta tag to the second meta tag, as to become:

```
<meta name="description" content="Example"/>

<meta property="og:description" content="Example"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?s)<meta name="description" content="(.*?)"/>.*?<meta property="og:description" content="\K.*?(?="\/>)`
- Replace with: `\1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

The Generic of this kind of replace is:

- Find what: `(?s)START-TAG-1(.*?)FINAL-TAG-1.*?START-SECOND-TAG\K.*?(?=FINAL-SECOND-TAG)`
- Replace with: `\1`